# How do I get this query to work correctly?

Tags: sql, database

```
WITH company_size(comp_id, employee_count) AS (
SELECT comp_id, count(*)
FROM position NATURAL JOIN works
GROUP BY comp_id),

total_salaries(total_salaries) AS( 
    SELECT sum(pay_rate)
    from position)

SELECT comp_id, employee_count, total_salaries
FROM company_size NATURAL JOIN total_salaries
WHERE employee_count = (SELECT max(employee_count) 
                        FROM company_size);
```

So this is the query that I'm working on. I got it to work to get biggest employer in terms of number of employees but now I have to find the total amount of salaries and wages paid from that certain company.. I have total_salaries, but that just gives me the sum of ALL companies. How would it look like to just get the total salaries from that one resulted company?

Comment: Your syntax is distinctly not MySQL (unless version 8).  Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Oops sorry! Gonna change it as its Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Please click on 'edit' and edit your tags to appropriately say you are using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Is English your 1st language? Because you describe things very unclearly/sloppily. Force yourself to write enough clear grammatical sentences & phrases to say *exactly* what you mean. Don't just hope that an unclear/sloppy sentence/phrase might be suggestive enough. Eg you don't want "one company", you want *a table of certain rows*--the rows where ...? Anyway--there's just one max employee count, but *more* than one company can have it.

Comment: This question is complete. Everyone understood my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your tables to work with, but I would expect that for a `NATURAL JOIN` to work between `company_size` and `total_salaries` they would both need to have a column to join on.  As it is, `total_salaries` returns a single column with a single row.  Perhaps if it grouped on `comp_id` you would get better results.

Or to make it even easier, just move `sum(pay_rate)` out of the `total_salaries` and into the `company_size` query. you can then just do away with the `total_salaries` query and the join to `company_size`:

```
WITH company_size(comp_id, employee_count, total_salries) AS (
  SELECT comp_id
       , count(*)
       , sum(pay_rate)
    FROM position NATURAL JOIN works
   GROUP BY comp_id
)
SELECT comp_id
     , employee_count
     , total_salaries
  FROM company_size
 WHERE employee_count = (SELECT max(employee_count) 
                           FROM company_size);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. You were getting the sum for all companies because you're just selecting the value in the total_salaries query, you're not joining it to anything. Adding an id field and a group by will aggregate the data, then you just need to join it to something. Hope that helps.

```
WITH company_size(comp_id, employee_count) AS (
SELECT comp_id, count(*)
FROM position NATURAL JOIN works
GROUP BY comp_id),

total_salaries(total_salaries, comp_id) AS( 
    SELECT sum(pay_rate), comp_id
    FROM position
    GROUP BY comp_id)

SELECT comp_id, employee_count, total_salaries
FROM company_size cs INNER JOIN total_salaries ts ON cs.comp_id = ts.comp_id
WHERE employee_count = (SELECT max(employee_count) 
                        FROM company_size);
```

Comment: A `NATURAL JOIN` shouldn't have an `ON` clause. Does this actually run ??